# pyodbc trusted connection not working on IIS

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, windows, iis

I'm building a Python web app on Flask that use pyodbc to read data from a SQL Server database. Only trusted connection is allowed per the database's policy.

When I tried on my local, it works perfectly well. But when I hosted it on IIS (via WFastCGI) it's not working (Internal Server Error is raised) - failed to connect on below:

pyodbc.connect(blabla,trusted_connection = yes)

Just want to know how the user can get their credential and then continue connection to the SQL.

Comment: what's the error message that's thrown?  what does your actual call look like within the code?

Comment: What is your connection string and what is the application pool identity?

Comment: @Chris  Actually I do not know the error message, it's a web app and I could only see "Internal Server Error"

Comment: @LexLi The connection string is given above, application pool identity = "ApplicationPoolIdentity"

Comment: @MTANG no you didn’t give the connection string above.

Comment: @LexLi pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server} ;SERVER=someserver;Trusted_Connection=yes;')

Answer (score 0):

This call has worked for me in the past (connecting to SQL Server):

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(''''
                      TRUSTED_CONNECTION=Yes;
                      DRIVER={SQL Server};
                      SERVER={myServer};
                      DATABASE=myDB;''')
```

Comment: use this solution in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62387839/12274302