# python flask website running on iis not connecting to sql database when passing login credentials

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am a bit stuck here, so i made a test site to figure this out.

I have a python flask site and I have to use the domain login to login into sql database.  Here i wrote a quick test which sends the username and password to my db connection and will display the connection on the screen

```
@app.route("/", methods =['GET','POST']
def index():
    user = os.environ.get('username')
    pwd = os.environ.get('password')
    dbcon = db.sqlcon(user, pwd)
    return render_template("index.html", dbcon=dbcon

def dbcon(user, pwd):
    a="SQL Server"
    con = pyodbc.connect(f"DRIVER={a};Database=customer;Server=SQL1;Username={user};pwd{pwd}")
    return con
```

Again, very simple and this works on my local machine.  When i upload to the iis server, it does not connect to the database.  I tried install an odbc driver on the iis server, but still wouldn't connect.

I also checked to see, when i go onto the site from the server, it does capture my login information.

Any help is duly appreciated

DamnGroundHog

Comment: changed user to ```user=request.environ['REMOTE_USER']```  This now displays the remote user name successfully.  how can I use this username to connect to sql.  ```Trusted_Connections="Yes";``` Is still not working.

Comment: You either have Trusted_Connection in your connection string or Username+Password, but not both. Trusted_Connection will only work on Windows using IIS with Windows Authentication enabled. If you're somehow capturing the login's actual password from `os.environ.get('password')` then it sounds like you have Basic Authentication enabled instead.

Comment: I removed the user and password and only enabled ```Trusted_Connections=Yes"```  Is there anything i should put int the web.config file?

Answer (score 0):

I use flask on IIS and work perfect wit SQL.(thanks from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62387839/12274302) ).

First step create SQL authentication user on SQL server with SQL server management.

second step connect with this code:

```
coonection = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=. ;Database=MyDBName;uid=UserNameWhenCreateUser; pwd=PasswordWhenCreateUser;")   
CU = coonection .cursor()
```

result:
[image]